# Response.Redirect with headers

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I'm trying to set the headers and redirecting to a different page like this -

```
Response.Headers.Add("id", "testtest");
Response.Redirect("http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx");
```

And in the `page_load` of somepage.aspx, I'm checking the request for headers -

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["id"]))
{
   // do something with "id"
}
```

But `Request["id"`] is always null. How do I get the values of the header in the new page? I do not want to use query strings.

Thanks!

Update:

Here's a little more detail -- I have two ASP.NET v4 web applications (Site 1 and Site 2) running on two different machines. Site 1 has just one aspx form and it has only one button on it. On button click, I hit the database and get the value I need and should pass it on to Site 2. In the Global.asax of Site 2, I'll be reading the header information received from Site 1 and use the value.

Update #2:

I was able to get it to work --

```
 Response.Write(
                    string.Format(
                        @"<form action='{0}' id='test' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='key' value={1} /></form>
                  <script type='text/javascript'>
                     document.getElementById('test').submit();
                  </script> ",
                        "http://www.somesite.com", "1234"));
```

In the destination site, I was able to get the value using -

```
Request["key"]
```

Comment: Part of sharing cases like this, is to post an answer and mark it to save others time to read all the comments and answers to find the solution!

Answer (score 19):

HTTP headers are valid only for the current response. When you set a redirect the current response contains your custom header but when the browser follows the redirect location those headers are no longer present. Furthermore you are using `Request["id"]` in the other page so you need to sent the value as query string:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx?id=test");
```

Comment: I don't want the users to see the id in the query string. If I were to use somepage.aspx?id=test, I should be using Request.QueryString["id"] to get the value of id.

Comment: If you don't want users to see the id the only way to achieve this is to use Session. HTTP headers are also *visible* by users.

Comment: I understand HTTP headers will be visible if the users use some HTTP header sniffing utility and that's okay as most people don't bother. I could be wrong, but I don't think I could use Session as the source site and destination site are on two different machines.

Comment: OK, I understand. You cannot use headers and redirect for the reasons mentioned in my post. Another possibility is to generate an HTML form with a hidden input and POST to the other script instead of GET. This way the id value will be in the POST body and not visible in the query string.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please provide an example? Can I just do it with Response.Write(<html script>)? Or may be ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript or something?

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to add headers to the http request but initiating one by either a user action through a browser or other programs or by sending such a request on your own.

So you could simply make use of one of those http clients in the.Net Framework like the `HttpClient` or `HttpWebRequest` and send a custom request with whichever headers you want instead of calling `Response.Redirect`.

Yet it's possible to add custom headers to http Response message only in [IIS](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/redirectheaders/add). Still no way to control the consequent request headers when performing a redirect.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <redirectHeaders>
            <add name="X-Custom-Redirect-Header" value="MyRedirectValue" />
         </redirectHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing the id through Headers, use Cookies.

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("id", someId));
Response.Redirect("http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx");
```

You can get this id using the following code:

```
Request.Cookies["id"];
```

Comment: Keep in mind this won't work across different sites as is the case in the OP.  There may be some tricks you can do when both sites are in the same domain, but one site cannot read another site's cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Response.Headers.Add("id", "testtest"); 
is not having the expected effect, because you have never sent Response to the client. If you are using Response.Redirect, you are simply redirecting to the url and the Request object is not hyderated with your previous Response params.

You can use some form AppContext/Session mechanism to pass params between these two pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Server.Transfer("http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx");`? This might get you the data you need. If not, you'll have to post the data to the form on your originating page if you don't want to use the Session variable.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use Server.Transfer as the URL won't change. Could you please elaborate on "post the data to the form on your originating page"?

Comment: I assumed based on your original description that you could put this information in a hidden field, which would allow it to show up on the new page after using Server.Transfer (or submitting a form, if there is one). Darin suggested much the same thing -- if you can post more details about your original page, we can suggest ways for you to get this information between URLs. It's hard to tell from the current description if you can use a form on the originating page and what your other technical constraints are/might be.

Comment: I've tried this -- 

Response.Write(
                    string.Format(
                        @"<form action='{0}' id='test' method='POST'><input type='hidden' id='key' value={1} /></form>
                  <script type='text/javascript'>
                     document.getElementById('test').submit();
                  </script> ",
                        "http://www.somepage.com/", "1234")); 

But when I do Request["key"] on the destination site, it is null. Not sure where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I got it!! In the hidden field above, I should be using the "name" attribute instead of "id" to be able to use it in the destination site. This worked -- 

Response.Write( string.Format( @"<form action='{0}' id='test' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='key' value={1} /></form> <script type='text/javascript'> document.getElementById('test').submit(); </script> ", "http://www.somepage.com/", "1234"));

Comment: Congrats! Glad I could help(?). You should post your resulting decision as an answer itself (possibly with some more details about when you're writing that HTML, and why you have to use response.write instead of just writing the HTML to the ASPX page) and accept it.

Comment: Thanks, you and Darin helped me in pointing to the right direction. I'll create another post and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of these solutions worked, I Found a way that let me use the Response contructor and redirect by using the http protocol.

```
new Response(null, {                                                                                                               
   status: 307,                                                                                                                          
   headers: {                                                                                                                            
      'Set-Cookie': `myCookie=432556; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict`,                                               
      Location: '/',                                                                                                                    
   },                                                                                                                                    
});
```