# Cannot Get custom header at client side using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, http-headers

I am trying to send a response with custom header named "x-custom-token" set at server side, and the browser is receiving it. But at client side. I am not able to get it.

This is my server side code (.Net framework).

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
//[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods:"*",exposedHeaders: "x-custom-token")]
[AllowCrossSiteAttribute]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(string account, string password)
{
    if (account == null || password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("account or password is null");
    }

    try
    {
        if (this.userService.CheckUserData(account, password))
        {
            string roleName = this.userService.GetRole(account, password);

            string token = this.jWTService.GenerateToken(account, roleName);

            Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-custom-token");
            Response.AppendHeader("x-custom-token", token);
            Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");
            return Json("Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 204;
            Response.Redirect("~/Login/login");
            return Json("no permission");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        Response.StatusDescription = ex.Message;
        Response.Redirect("~/Login/login");
        return Json("no permission");
    }
}
```

And this is client side (Javascript):

```js
const loginButton = document.getElementsByClassName("login")[0];
loginButton.addEventListener("click", async function () {
const account = document.getElementsByClassName("accountInput")[0].value;
const password = document.getElementsByClassName("passwordInput")[0].value;
const body = `account=${account}&password=${password}`;
const re = await sendRequest("/Login/login", "POST", { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }, body);
if (re.status === 200) {
    console.log(re);
    console.log(re.headers.get("access-control-expose-headers"));
    console.log(re.headers.get("x-custom-token"));
    console.log(re.headers.get("x-aspnet-version"));
    debugger
    window.location.href = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}:${Number(44398)}/Home/Index`;
}
else {
    alert(`response status: ${re.status} ${re.json()}`);
}
}, false);
```

In this line of code `console.log(re.headers.get("x-custom-token"));` I always get null....
the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`  is also added.
I am sure the browser has the response with this custom header
[browser response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGeP8.jpg)

This is my `sendRequest()` method:

```js
async function sendRequest(path, method, headers, body) {
    const protocol = window.location.protocol;
    const domainName = window.location.hostname;
    const port = "44398"

    let options = {
        method: method,
        headers: headers,
    }

    if (body) {
        options.body = body;
    }

    const response = await fetch(`${protocol}//${domainName}:${port}${path}`, options)

    return response;
}
```

I am trying to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Can you try commenting out the redirect line in the C# code? Perhaps the redirect is not preserving the header.

Comment: and what is your sendRequest service using? xhr fetch ?

Comment: my sendRequest() service is using fetch

Comment: i commentted out the Response.Redirect(), and it is work, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before returning   return Json("Ok"); you are callin  Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");
which is redirecting to new get request instead of returning the response to the current client call.

instead of calling  Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index"); before return return Json("Ok"); ,
you can remove it from server side and handle at the response of ajax request at client-side in javascript function.

please see the below url for your understanding.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070430/response-redirect-with-headers#:~:text=Still%20no%20way%20to%20control,headers%20when%20performing%20a%20redirect.&text=Response.,-Headers.&text=Redirect%2C%20you%20are%20simply%20redirecting,params%20between%20these%20two%20pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070430/response-redirect-with-headers#:%7E:text=Still%20no%20way%20to%20control,headers%20when%20performing%20a%20redirect.&text=Response.,-Headers.&text=Redirect%2C%20you%20are%20simply%20redirecting,params%20between%20these%20two%20pages).